# Spring Cloud Configuration recommended architecture in data center

Tags: spring-cloud

> I have been playing with Spring Cloud Configuration. I like the simplicity of the solution and the fact that it uses git as it's default configuration store.
>
> There are two aspects I need to figure out before pushing it as a solution for centralized configuration management.
>   The aspects are:
>
> > High availability
> >
> > How to gradually roll out configuration changes (to support canary releases)
>
> If you already implemented this in your data center or just playing with that please share your ideas!
>   Also I would like to hear from the creators, how they see the recommended deployment in single/cross data-center environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Config Server itself is stateless, so you can spin up as many as these as you need and find them via eureka.  Underneath the server itself, the git implementation you point to needs to be highly available as well.  So if you point to github (private or public), then git is as available as github is.  If the config server can't reach git it will continue to serve what it has checked out even if it is stale.

As far as gradual config changes, you could use a different branch and configure the canary to use that branch via `spring.cloud.config.label` and them merge the branch.  You could also use profiles (eg `application-<profilename>.properties`) and configure the canary to use the specified profile.

I think the branch makes a little more sense, because you wouldn't have to reconfigure the non-canary nodes to use the new profile each time, just configure canary to use the branch.

Either way, the only time apps see config chages (when using spring cloud config client) is on startup or when you `POST` to `/refresh` on each node.  You can also `POST` to `/bus/refresh?destination=<servicename>` if you use the Spring Cloud Bus to refresh all instances of a service at once.

Comment: What are the options for non-git repository, native profile based system?

Comment: You can use a filesystem, or more recently hashicorp vault or a database via jdbc